# CSS opacity not applied to Adobe pdf reader opened in iframe

Tags: css, browser, iframe, modal-dialog, adobe-reader

Applying a background to entire page with some transparency does not apply to a pdf opened in an iframe. Why is the PDF not being hidden by the background?

```
 <iframe src="http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/401k_mistakes.pdf" />     

  <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; 
     z-index: 100; 
     background-color: gray; 
     width: 1000px; 
     height: 1000px; 
     position: absolute; 
     opacity: 0.8;">
 </div>
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/JXT5V/3/  (example doesn't work in Chrome)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change this behavior.

Comment: Yup, I think this is the PDF plugin overlapping everything else. You could try an `<object>` and see whether it behaves differently but I doubt it

Answer (score 3):

The browser is not rendering that part of the screen, the PDF plugin is. The plugin will not honor your CSS.  Whether the background/transparency renders in front of the plugin's content depends on the interaction between the particular browser and the particular plugin (Adobe isn't the only PDF plugin) and you have no way to control that.